# Difference between UUID UUID + Id

Tags: uuid

what is the difference between these 2 solutions:

UUID as primary key VS
 auto-increment ID as primary key + new UUID field

Comment: Please add your DBMS tag.

Answer (score 0):

At the most basic level, you've got an extra `int` column with the second solution.

If your primary key is a clustered index, then the first will essentially store new rows in a random place in the table, and the second will store new rows at the end of the table.

If you have a huge number of independent new inserts happening at the same time (for instance, an OLTP-type situation), then spreading the inserts across your table *may* allow more inserts to happen simultaneously, faster.

Also, all indexes use your clustered key to identify rows in the index. A clustered key that's an `int` takes up much less space that a UUID key in other indexes. If you have a large table and/or lots of indexes, this may be a noticeable difference in disk space requirements.

Outside of that OLTP-type scenario, unless you absolutely require a UUID column, I'd be inclined to use a simple `int` auto-increment PK, without the UUID.

Comment: *"clustered key"*: Not all DBMS have clustered indexes. And in some (like SQL Server), we have the option to decide if the table is clustered or not.

Comment: Hence, "*If* your primary key is a clustered index..."